# How to sort a ArrayList () by getting as a parameter (in a class file)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compareto

Here I want to sort an array list of books data type. But I'm getting an error message. Please tell me how to do this. I can use arr instead of an Arraylist. But when I change it to Arraylist I'm getting an error message.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Books implements Comparable<Books> {

private int bookNo;
private String bookTitle;
private String bookAuthor;


//Getters and Setters

@Override
public int compareTo(ArrayList<Books> books) {
    return 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Books implements Comparable<Books> {

    //instance variables and getter/setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Books books) {
       //TODO comparison logic
       // compare books to this object
       return 0;
    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String ar){
       List<Books> list = ....;
       Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

Google for Comparable/Comparator in java and you will find tons of examples.